# What does "bring a date" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> So I'm guessing you had an extra ticket and couldn't decide which one
>   of you got to bring a date?

What does "bring a date" mean in this sentence? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The relevant definition of *date* here is [4b: "a person with whom one has a usually romantic date, *bringing a date to the dance*"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *date* has quite a few different meanings.

One of them is to refer to the day on which something occurs:

> a : the time at which an event occurs
>
> > the date of his birth
>
> > on this date in history

<sup>(all quoted definitions from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/date))</sup>

This meaning leads to the re-use of the word to refer to a meeting scheduled for a particular date:

> a : an appointment to meet at a specified time
>
> > set up a date with her lawyer;

But without some context suggesting otherwise (as with the lawyer example above), this is specifically a *romantic* outing:

> especially : a social engagement (see engagement 1a) between two persons that often has a romantic character
>
> > asked her out on a date

From that definition, the word date can also be applied to the *person* you would go out on the date with:

> b : a person with whom one has a usually romantic date
>
> > bringing a date to the dance

This is the meaning you have in your sentence: with several people going, and only one extra ticket, they could not *all* bring dates. Rather than allowing one to bring a date (i.e. make the outing romantic for them, while leaving the others without a romantic partner, which is often awkward), they instead offered the ticket to the speaker (or so the speaker hypothesizes, anyway).

Comment: Well, a downvote on this purely-objective answer is flabbergasting. Does someone object to drawing connections between related usages of the word as an aid to comprehension and recall?